# Is the similar function random.uniform() supported in the OSL?

Tags: scripting, osl

Python has a random module that allows you to get the following values

a = round(random.uniform(min, max), 4) - float number in the given range with rounding

b = random.random() - float number in range 0-1

Is it possible to implement these functions in OSL?
I tried different ways with rand() or random value() but the output is error message.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Random value between 0 and 1.

```
float random_value = noise("uperlin", Seed)

Random value between min and max.

float random_uniform = min + random_value * (max - min)
```

Comment: I don't know OSL, but perlin noise probably doesn't yield uniform distribution and tends to be closer to `0.5`?